# How to attach android source in IntelliJ 10?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to attach the android source code to intellij 10. Anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > double-click the Android Platform > source path> navigate to the source on your computer!

Comment: I want to add the directions for IntelliJ 11: File > Project Structure > SDKs > Android Platform > Sourcepath tab > + (bottom left) > Navigate to the source folder.

Not sure why BoltClock deleted my answer for being "exactly the same" as your answer, because it's not. Different versions, different places to make this change.