# add android source code to intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

how do you add android source code to

```
 intelli j 10
```

so that i can browse android code in the IDE? yes there is a question and answer here
     [How to attach android source in IntelliJ 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366503/how-to-attach-android-source-in-intellij-10)

```
but the answer fell short, the last step is 'navigate to the source on your computer!',
```

where is the source? where do i download it?

thanks

Comment: Googled "download Android source": [Downloading the Source Tree](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using some old Android Platform, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998234/104891).

Otherwise sources should be already downloaded by the **SDK Manager** and available on your hard drive in the SDK folder, for example:

```
%ANDROID_SDK%/sources/android-16
```

This directory can be attached to IntelliJ IDEA Android SDK. I also recommend updating to the latest IDEA version, Android support is much better than in IDEA 10.