# How can I navigate through the Android SDK source in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I code in IntelliJ IDEA,I want to navigate to the SDK Source, such as the source of `TextView.setText`, and the comments on it.

How would I import the source into IDEA just like in Eclipse?

Comment: I know, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13080731/104891).

IntelliJ IDEA configures the sources automatically for you if they are present in the Android SDK that you have downloaded using the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) tool:

[image]

If the sources folder is missing, download the SDK again and add it to the Sourcepath of the Android Platform in IntelliJ IDEA.